# Why Ternary operation failure not cought in try catch

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, ternary-operator

I was referring to code [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cc-ternary-operator-some-interesting-observations/). Then I modified it as below, to catch the failure. But the code fails without catching the exception. How to handle (catch) this failure?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int test = 0;
cout << "test set to 0" << endl;
try {
    cout << (test ? "A String" : 0) << endl;
} catch(...) {
    cout << "Exception" << endl;
}
cout << "Test done" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The common type is a pointer, and dereferencing a null pointer leads to *undefined behavior* and not an exception. And if it crashes then it's because of a different and lower-level "exception", not a C++ exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++, unlike most other languages, has a notion of ***undefined behavior***. That means that invalid actions do not lead to an exception, but to a crash, data corruption or really anything else. An *exception* in C++ is something that the code explicitly `throw`s and `catch`es. That's not the case in your code.

The result of `(test ? "A String" : 0)` is `const char *`. So the `0` is converted to `const char *`, i.e. a NULL pointer. The standard library has an [overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) for `operator <<` that expects `const char *` to be a non-NULL C-string.

That is, `operator <<` simply does not check the input parameter for NULL. And deferencing a NULL pointer is undefined behavior. On most systems it will lead to a segmentation fault at the OS level and program termination.

For completeness, in MSVC you can compile with `/EHa` to treat SEH exceptions as C++ exceptions, then `catch(...)` will also catch those. But don't use this feature, as it can lead to resource leaks and non-portable, unmaintainable code.

Answer (score 5):

Your code doesn't throw any exceptions, type of `"A String"` is `const char*`, so a pointer, and `0` can be evaluated as `NULL`, a pointer as well, which means that `test ? "A String" : 0` returns `const char*`, no errors there.

Also I don't think you know how exceptions work, if your code had an error like
`test ? std::string{"A String"} : nullptr`, that error will be a compile time error, not an exception, as the compiler will be unable to find a common type for both types.